# Is there any way to detect any installed application from browser using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, windows

I am stuck somewhere in my functionality where I want to check any specific application is installed or not?

For example : I have installed Microsoft Excel or MS-Teams in my windows laptop and from browser I want to check these application is installed or not? If it is installed then I want to show alert that particular application is installed.

Note : I do not have any code snippet for same to attach with Question. If you need any further information the please do let me know.

Answer (score 3):

No, browser-based JavaScript code can't look to see if an arbitrary application is installed on the computer the browser is running on. It would be a massive security hole.

Certain applications or libraries install things that are then shown in the browser's `userAgent` string (for instance, Internet Explorer used to include information about which version(s) of the .Net framework are installed), but in the general case, you can't detect this (and Edge doesn't do that anymore).